# windows 10 пропало безопасное извлечение устройств

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

Иконка есть, нажимается, выпадает список, но он какой то неактивный стал. нажать нельзя. 
Из-за этого теперь не могу устройства usb передавать на vmware

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вроде бы новость была, что в Windows 10 теперь можно безопасно извлекать флешки на ходу без безопасного извлечения.

Answer (score 0):

В Windows 10 ввели возможность безопасно извлекать флешки без безопасного извлечения, прямо на ходу.

Есть 2 режима работы с флешкой:

1. Быстрый- запрещает системе кешировать данные => флешка готова к извлечению в любой момент, но побочный эффект- это сниженная производительность, что может быть заметно при записи больших данных. Режим включен по умолчанию.
2. Производительный- кеширование присутствует => нельзя на ходу извлекать флешки и пункт безопасного извлечения снова присутствует.

Менять режимы можно в разделе управления дисками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пруф](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4495263/windows-10-1809-change-in-default-removal-policy-for-external-media).

Comment: Лучше бы ссылку на официальный сайт микрософта, а не на статью в газете.

Comment: Ок, поправил...

Comment: Не "с недавних пор", а можно было уже давным давно. Эта опция существует с незапамятных времен. "Недавно" поменялось лишь установка по умолчанию.

Comment: ну это не решает моей проблемы. пропала сама кнопка извлечь и я сказал у меня проблемы не могу флешку передать в vmware а раньше мог без проблем и безопасно извлекалась стандартным способом